# Выброс исключения std::invalid_argument

Tags: c++, исключения

У меня есть контейнер `map<string, int> st` и я с помощью метода `find` нахожу по ключу значение. Я знаю, что если этот метод не находит переданный ключ, то он вернет итератор `st.end()`. Но мне нужно если такого ключа нет выбросить исключение `std::invalid_argument`. Как это можно осуществить?

Comment: очень просто:   if(st.find(...) == st.end()) throw std::invalid_argument(...);

Answer (score 1):

`std::invalid_argument` для данной задачи можно выбросить только самостоятельно.

Если подойдёт другой наследник `std::exception`, то начиная с C++11 в `std::map` есть метод [`at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at), который ищет значение по ключу и выбрасывает `std::out_of_range`. В отличие от `find()` он возвращает не итератор, а значение.